# Android AlarmManager not working on Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, alarmmanager

Another complain about AlarmManager (hoping for a quick solution).
I am using the Android *Emulator* for developing.
I found an allegedly working example so I tried to use it.
I did the following:

1. Added a receiver string to the manifest file.

   ```
    <receiver android:name=".SchHandler" android:process=":remote" />
   ```
2. Created the main activity and used its onCreate.

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       SchHandler handler = new SchHandler(this, bundle, 1);
   }
   ```
3. Created a BroadcastReceiver to create and listen to alarms.

   ```
   public class SchHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
       private final String REMINDER_BUNDLE = "ReminderBundle";

       public SchHandler (Context context, Bundle extras, int timeoutInSeconds) {    
           Toast.makeText(context, "Scheduling...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.d("Debug", "Sch");

           AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, SchHandler.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

           Toast.makeText(context, "Time:" + System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
           System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, 5000, pendingIntent);    
       }

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.e(REMINDER_BUNDLE, "Receive");
          Toast.makeText(context, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
   ```

I tried it with *set*, *setRepeating*, nothing worked. What else should I try?

Comment: That's odd. I don't see any problems in your code. Could it be that `onReceive()` is executed, but the toast is not shown?

Comment: If executed then the Log should show it (_Log.d_). But nothing happens.

Comment: Then your `BroadcastReceiver` is not being registered properly. Try adding `<intent-filter>` with some action to your `<receiver>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and setting that action to the `Intent`.

Comment: I added to the reciever:  `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mypage.SCH"/></intent-filter>
            </receiver>` and this to my code:  `intent.setAction("com.mypage.SCH");` but still no luck.

Comment: It's just weird that there are so many questions regarding the AlarmManager with this particular problem and yet there is no 'simple' solution. It seems like the component itself is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the name of my receiver to its fully qualified version, and it turned out that I used its package name instead of the class name. After setting it properly, I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The root of evil might be the `android:process=":remote"` in your `<receiver>` tag. Try removing it.